# Javascript file load fallback. Alternative to document.write()

Tags: javascript, jquery, document.write, fallback

You might be familiar with the good old Jquery load fallback:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://example.com/jquery.js"></script>')</script>
```

But I read here and there: don’t use `document.write`, is bad for your health, it does not work on Chrome (It’s working for me, Chrome 78).
So I’m trying to replace it, but I’m not able to find a solution that will load synchronously the new js file, before `DOM` loaded is triggered.
And what ends happening with a `DOM` manipulation alternative is that the browser consideres the `DOM` is loaded and all `$(document).ready()` fail with “*$ is not defined*”.

```
function Jqfallback() { 
    var j = document.createElement('script');    
    j.src = 'https://example.com/jquery.js'; 
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(j); 
}
(window.jQuery || Jqfallback() );
```

No matter where I put this script, or the new JS file, which in this case `('head')[0]` is already before all other JS which are in the body, it loads it “asyncronically”.

Is there another option or I continue rocking `document.write()` in late 2019?

Answer (score 1):

It takes a bit of time to load and parse JQuery. So use a (small) *timeout* after appending the script.

This snippet wraps conditional loading in a immediately executed anonymous function:

```js
(myScripting => {
    if (!window.$) { 
      let j = document.createElement('script');    
      j.src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js'; 
      document.querySelector('head').appendChild(j);
      setTimeout( myScripting, 200 );
    } else {
      myScripting();
    }
})(JqIsLoadedSoMyScriptingCanStart);

// put your main scripting in here
function JqIsLoadedSoMyScriptingCanStart() {
  // extra check
  if (!window.$) {
    alert("Sorry, JQuery is not loaded, can't continue");
    return;
  }
  console.log("JQuery in place?");
  console.log($("head script")[1]);
}
```

```html
<script src="cantLoadThis"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the code that uses jQuery in the **onload()** function.

```
var jQuery1 = document.createElement('script');
jQuery1.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js";

jQuery1.onload = function () {
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        $.when(
               $.getScript("https://someOtherScript.js"),  //if you need
               $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
               $(deferred.resolve);
        })
        ).done(function () {
        console.log("all scripts loaded!!");
        doNextTask(); //some other code which uses jQuery
});
};
```

Append jQuery to your document in **onreadystatechange**

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    // document is ready. 
    document.head.appendChild(jQuery1);
 }
 }
```